# Is it possible to order entries by Entry type title/slug

Tags: templating, ordering, order

I would like to order my entries by the entry type they have, so for instance:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('more-info').order('type') %}
```

However, this orders by entry type ID, and not by title, alphabetically. Can this be done? I've tried `order('type.title')`, but no luck (= DB error) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to order by the name or handle of Entry Types. To order by the ID of your Entry Types use `'typeId'` as the value:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('more-info').order('typeId') %}
```

Now you only have to create your Entry Types alphabetically ;)

Comment: Create them alphabetically. Jup, that's nice. Until you want to add one later on ;)